# Join multiple Points to Polygon and concatenate joined point values of column into Polygon column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, geospatial, geopandas

My data:

```
Points:
    ID HN Street 
    1  5  Examplestreet
    2  6  Examplestreet
    3  2  Otherstreet
    4  2  Anotherstreet
Polygons:
    Name
    Firstpolygon
    Secondpolygon
    Otherpolygon
```

So I want to performe a one(polygon) to many (points) spatial join and concatenate the joined valus from the points `HN` column to a new column "all_HN" in the Polygonsfile.

So the result should look like this:

```
Name          all_HN
Firstpolygon  5,6   -> if the points ID1 and ID2 lie within the same polygon (`"Firstpolygon"`)
Secondpolygon 2     -> point ID3 within the `"Secondpolygon"`
Otherpolygon  NULL  -> no point within "Otherpolygon"
and so on
```

I thought of solving this with geopandas. (I have about 200.000 Points and 100.000 polygons)
Using the following code:

```
from geopandas import gpd

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('MyPointsFile) # or geojson etc 
polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('MyPolygonsFile.shp') 
pointInPoly = gpd.sjoin(points, polys, op='within',how='inner')
```

Now I thought using something like:

```
pointInPoly.groupby('index_right')['HN_left'].sum()
```

But instead of sum() the right command to concantinate all values of the matching points into a new column "all_HN".

Anyone, any idea how to solve this problem?Its also ok using another package and not geopandas.
Since geopandas is based on pandas an pandas solution should also work.
It would also be enough to just append all columns of the matches to the corresponding Polygons Tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group those values in a list instead of summing them, you can do the following (using an example dataframe without geometries, but the result after `merge` instead of `sjoin` should be similar):

```
In [53]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'index': [1, 2, 3]})

In [54]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'HN': [5, 6, 2]})

In [55]: res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')

In [56]: res
Out[56]: 
   index key   HN
0      1   a  5.0
1      1   a  6.0
2      2   b  2.0
3      3   c  NaN

In [57]: res.groupby('index')['HN'].apply(list)
Out[57]: 
index
1    [5.0, 6.0]
2         [2.0]
3         [nan]
Name: HN, dtype: object
```

If you don't want the `[nan]`, you can adapt the function that is passed to `apply` a bit.